# Wordpress custom post type and permalink rewriting

Tags: wordpress

I'm struggling with a problem I'm not able too solve.
I've spent a lot of hourse in codex documentation without any luck.
I've created a custom post type called "Products". Products will be available in many language. Products permalink is something like: mysite.com/products/product-name What I need instead is something like this: mysite.com/language/products/product-name.
What I need to create the permalink? Have I to add some fancy rule with WP_Rewrite?
Is it possibile to have custom post type as page child's?
I don't really need custom taxonomy so if you know a better solution fell free to write.
Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a plugin for wordpress to gracefully handle multiple languages.

I suggest you check out [wpml.org](http://www.wpml.org)

For how the Wordpress Multilingual plugin works with custom posts types, check out their informative [blog post](http://wpml.org/2010/05/custom-types-in-wordpress-3-simplified-our-site/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've brillantly solved the problem above with use of wpml.